# Run external command silently

Tags: vbscript, cmd

I am trying to run cmd code from vbscript (vbs file) silently.

I have tried this, but it doesnt hide the cmd window.

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "cmd.exe /K ping example.org"
Set oShell = Nothing
```

What is the correct way to do that ?

Comment: `oShell.run "cmd.exe /K ping example.org",0,True` would make it silent but `/K` would prevent the script from ever finishing since that tells CMD to leave the prompt open. Is this what you really want to do? Or do you have a bigger question?

Comment: How can I open multiple cmd.exe ? I need to ping multi sites in same time.

Comment: How you have it now you would get no information returned. What is the reason for pinging those external sites? Want to be sure we are fixing your [real](http://xyproblem.info/) issue.

Comment: 1- The cmd request has been already included in the question. 2* The reason? Thats pretty much off-topic.

Comment: You may get better answers if people understand what you're trying to achieve in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "cmd.exe ping example.org",0,True
Set oShell = Nothing
```

As per the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx) for `.Run` you can use the optional parameter for `intWindowStyle`, which will hide *most* windows from the screen, by setting it to 0. The True is to tell the operation to wait until completion before completing the script. That is of course optional.

If you hide the window you need to remove `/K` or else the script will never complete.

Comment: By telling "script will never complete", you mean the script won't stop, right ?

Comment: @user198989 Correct. The cmd prompt will remain open. Since you have no way to interact with it via the GUI you would need to kill the process for both it and wscript.exe